# Как обойти текст при наведении на svg элемент?

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть следующий код, при наведении на блок у `svg` должна меняться обводка, но если наводить на текст, который находится над самим `svg` элементом, то естественно обводка не появляется, пробовал делать вот так:

```
.accordion_name h2:hover svg {
  stroke: orange;
}
```

Но это не привело ни к каким результатам, что можно сделать в данной ситуации?

И сразу еще вопрос, я разместил вот этот svg блок относительно родительского блока, мне нужно что бы текст всего был в районе данного треугольника:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если текст будет больше, то он выйдет за пределы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оно так и должно происходить с моим выполнением задачи, но есть ли способ сделать это правильно: Что бы если текст выходил за пределы треугольника, то треугольник делался больше в ширину, либо другие решения (Пробовал задавать максимальную ширину блоку с текстом, но не помогло).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  backgoround-color: #ddddd;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 30px;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.accordion_item {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.accordion_name {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.accordion_name h2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  display: inline-block;
}

.accordion_name h2:hover svg {
  stroke: orange;
}

svg {
  stroke: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  fill: #dddddd;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

svg:hover {
  stroke: orange;
}

.accordion_content {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="accordion_item">
    <div class="accordion_name">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -1 202 34" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d='M200 32 L0 32, 0 0, 65 0, 110 32' stroke-width='1'/>
</svg>
      <h2>One accordiont line</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_content">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente molestias inventore cum. Eligendi ad quae, veritatis nostrum dolores doloremque culpa. Nam sequi omnis fugiat sed. Enim ipsum rerum iure quisquam.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_item">
    <div class="accordion_name">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -1 202 34" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d='M200 32 L0 32, 0 0, 65 0, 110 32' stroke-width='1'/>
</svg>
      <h2>One accordiont line</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_content">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente molestias inventore cum. Eligendi ad quae, veritatis nostrum dolores doloremque culpa. Nam sequi omnis fugiat sed. Enim ipsum rerum iure quisquam.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_item">
    <div class="accordion_name">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -1 202 34" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d='M200 32 L0 32, 0 0, 65 0, 110 32' stroke-width='1'/>
</svg>
      <h2>One accordiont line</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_content">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente molestias inventore cum. Eligendi ad quae, veritatis nostrum dolores doloremque culpa. Nam sequi omnis fugiat sed. Enim ipsum rerum iure quisquam.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: если речь конкретно о SVG то в нём перенос строки не работает

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi интересный, нестандартный вопрос, который требует нестандартного оригинального решения. Так как в svg текст не имеет автопереноса, как в HTML, текст не может при удлинении раздвинуть рамки ограничивающего контейнера, но вы не удаляйте вопрос, может найдется решение. (пока писал, Макс тоже ответил :))

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, я не собирался удалять, просто я взялся такой макет верстать, что там таких задач просто море подобных) Косые блоки повсюду, это пока самая трудная задача)

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi  сделай полностью на svg эти элементы , в нём сможешь сделать переносы ..но этот будет статично

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, в этом-то и дело, что нужно сделать это как-то динамично, что бы не абы как) Если это возможно вообще) Как-то же решают такие задачи)

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi  на svg не получится сделать резиновый ... только css

Comment: Зачем вам SVG в этой подаче? Используйте псевдоэлементы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте табы при помощи css:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  background: #eee;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

span:before,
span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 30px 0 0 50px; /* Изменяя цифру 50 можно менять угол наклона */
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ccc;
  z-index: -1;
}

span:after {
  margin-left: -2px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #eee;
}

div:hover {
  border-bottom-color: orange;
}

div:hover span {
  border-color: orange;
}

div:hover span:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent orange;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Пунтк 1</span></div>
```

Не будет проблем с шириной. Ограничение для текста тоже можно приделать используя `overflow: hidden` и `white-space: nowrap`. Можете дорабатывать как захочется.

Comment: У меня 125% в браузере, и в примере кода смещение вверх.

Comment: @Duoxx Если вы еще и оптимизацию для масштабированных элементов делаете, то время свое точно не жалеете. В таком случае можно поиграться со значениями или единицами, или сделать толщину линий больше. К слову, у меня в Chrome при 125% проблем нет.

Comment: Просто дело в том что я пользуюсь 125% так как у меня hi-dpi

Answer (score 4):

Вот таким образом заголовок косой и тянется в зависимости от текста

```js
$(function() {
  $(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

ul {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

ul h2 {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: pink;
  padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  color: red;
}

ul h2:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -70px;
  transform: skew(70deg);
}

ul h2:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  top: 20px;
  transform: skew(40deg);
}

ul li div {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <h2>длинный текст</h2>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam necessitatibus, exercitationem quos veritatis fugiat nostrum facilis minima eos consequatur nemo magnam magni accusantium voluptate dolore excepturi placeat. Earum aspernatur ad vero suscipit
      velit blanditiis reprehenderit quas temporibus saepe magnam animi placeat libero cum cupiditate accusantium dolorum voluptate modi rerum labore minima repudiandae, amet esse numquam!
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>длинее прошлого но текста для проверки</h2>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, est. Perspiciatis earum aut laborum deserunt fugit harum ab omnis, ad, qui repellat iste ex ratione ea vel. Quod, quia ipsa?
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>ещё длинеее чем прошлый</h2>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum reiciendis placeat distinctio officia error. Deserunt distinctio ab dolores, optio voluptate at laboriosam tempora accusamus incidunt nulla aperiam minus enim suscipit recusandae. Mollitia
      ducimus laboriosam temporibus maiores, tempora quasi natus, atque, error modi neque cupiditate dicta! Perspiciatis voluptate natus exercitationem atque?
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>вообще длинный текст и он растягивает название</h2>
    <div>
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil tempora distinctio labore libero est eos corporis quidem error repellendus quos veniam delectus voluptatem ullam nam quia quas, porro excepturi ducimus tenetur corrupti impedit pariatur sunt.
      Corporis eum laudantium porro consectetur.
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

Ещё вариант решения, как при наведении на svg элемент вывести большое количество текста. Для этого используется встроенная в svg возможность вывода `tooltip` при наведении на элемент.

Для этого надо разместить текст в теги - `<title>.....</title>` и обязательно обернуть svg элемент, для которого нужен длинный текст в групповые теги `<g>`

```css
.accordion_name:hover {
stroke:orange;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="202" height="34" viewBox="0 -1 202 34" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
<g>
 <path class="accordion_name" fill="transparent" stroke="grey" d='M200 32 L0 32, 0 0, 65 0, 110 32' stroke-width='1'/>
 
   <title>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</title>
</g> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Подсказки конечно тоже хорошо, но не думаю, что они бывают с таким немалым содержанием

Comment: @Arthur это конечно не решение, дал возможность автору проекта дополнительные простые средства к будущему основному решению. Наверняка в проекте, где-нибудь пригодится

Comment: Жаль поведение текста в SVG не самое лучшее=)
(нет переносов и т.д.)